# Resizing a BitmapButton image in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I have a list of bitmap buttons in a vertical sizer on the right.
I want to move the button and resize it when I click on it.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try like this

> self.toolbar.SetToolDisabledBitmap(self.recoveryBtn.Id,wx.Bitmap(RECOVERY_BTN_BMP))